# Why does px and em behave different in this case?

Tags: css, font-size

Using 1em as margin-left, on my paragraph with fontsize xx-large, gives me more margin than using 16px. How is that possible when 1em equals 16px?

Comment: `1em equals 16px` - **that is completely untrue**. [Please consult the W3C's own guides](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), the CSS specs, or at least MDN, before making claims that are easily debunked: to quote the source: "_The em and ex units depend on the font and may be different for each element in the document. The em is simply the font size._"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp - relax I just began

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `em` and `rem`. As others already wrote, `em` uses the element's font-size, whereas `rem` uses the basic fontsize . That can be defined as font-size for the `html` tag. If it's not defined, it falls back to the *browser* setting, which by default is 16px most of the time (but can also be changed by the user in the browser settings).

Answer (score 1):

`em` uses `font-size` of element applied, so its `px` size is not constant.
You can use `rem` unit, it always uses default `font-size` of browser(16px).

Answer (score 0):

[EM](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp#:%7E:text=The%20tag%20is%20used,an%20emphasis%2C%20using%20verbal%20stress.) uses the Element fontsize. Because you have given `font-size: xx-large` on your paragraph the fontsize is not 16px but 32px.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `em` unit for margin will use the `font-size` from the element it is applied to. Unless that is exactly `16px`, it will not match an explicitly `16px` margin.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.em {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.px {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p class="em">1</p>
<p class="px">2</p>
```